# SQL Server and PDF Files

Tags: database, pdf, uml, powerpoint

I am doing a UML modelation of a system in which I have to work with a data format I have never worked before - PDF files, ptt, etc .. my question is: can you explain me

1. how is a data file stored in the database, and how different it is from a string or an integer
2. how can I model that with UML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean mime type. Take a look [this](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Binary-Files-To-Database.aspx) and also [this](http://iamdotnetcrazy.blogspot.com/2010/11/finding-sql-mime-type-sql-server-mime.html)

Comment: hm ok thank you for the links. Can you give me an example on how can i modle a pdf file in a table?

Comment: hey i'm sorry i just found what what i was looking for. Instead of storing the files i need in the database, i store it in a folder instead and create a table with name, type, location and date field. The only thing i need in the database is the location of the file and not the file. Thank you very much.

Comment: this is simplest and best solution which all we developers apply in such condition.